# Trying to print out a diamond made of stars, and it cannot print even numbers

Tags: java

for one of my assignments I am required to print out stars in the shape of a diamond. When trying to print odd numbers, everything works out fine. However, when trying to print even numbered diamonds, the spacing in the middle lines is off, and a diamond is missing. Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong, and provide a possible fix?

```
public void printStarsDiamond(int d) 
{
    for (int i = 1; i < d; i = i + 2) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (d - i) / 2; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) 
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for (int i = d; i > 0; i = i - 2) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (d - i) / 2; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) 
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

[Desired result, if the user enters 6 (d = 6)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6XOc.png)

Comment: have you debugged your code?

Comment: the second loop:     for (int i = d - 1; i > 0; i = i - 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you notice your code, the second for loop is starting from 
i = d in

```
for (int i = d; i > 0; i = i - 2)
```

but your first loop is not ending at d, you are doing *i < d* there which will stop before d, so it will go from 1 to 5 if your d value is 6.

Simply change your second main for loop to start from d-1, here is the code

```
public void printStarsDiamond(int d) 
{
    for (int i = 1; i < d; i = i + 2) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (d - i) / 2; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) 
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for (int i = d-1; i > 0; i = i - 2) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (d - i) / 2; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) 
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much! i don't know how i missed that. thank you so so much!

Comment: Please upvote the answer and accept it if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The code below will print a diamond pattern using a single loop:

```
private static void PrintDiamondSingleLoop(int row) {
    row++;
    int mid = row/2;
    int midLeft = mid;
    int midRight = mid;
    int currentRow = 1;
    int currentColumn = 1;
     for (int i = 1; i <= row * row; i++) 
     {
               
        if(i % row == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("");

            if(currentRow < mid)
            {
                midLeft--;
                midRight++;

            }else
            { 

                midLeft++;
                midRight--;
            }

            currentColumn = 1;
            currentRow++;
        }

        if (currentColumn >= midLeft && currentColumn <= midRight)
        {

           
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        else
        {

           
            System.out.print(" ");

        }
                                  
        currentColumn++;
      }   
  }
```

(This code is taken from an article published on my website: https://programtown.com/how-to-print-diamond-pattern-using-single-for-loop-in-java/.)